# best way to keep user logged in with cookie and jwt?

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, token

I'm making an SPA with Laravel REST API and trying to keep it stateless.
Right now I'm trying to achieve proper JWT authentication and 'remember me' functionality.

1. On successful login the client receives a bearer-token in the
   payload (stored in **redux state**) which will be used for further
   requests as authorization.
2. On login I also generate a `httpOnly` cookie with an access-token
   and send it back.
3. On page reload I make a request (credentials: "include") and if the
   access-token is not expired, the client gets a new bearer-token.

- Is it a good approach?
- Is it safe to store the bearer token in redux state?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422889/is-it-safe-to-store-jwt-token-in-redux-store

Comment: first, a login is a state.  (just a pet-peeve of mine really, "REST" and "Stateless" are thrown around by people marketing frameworks in a way that makes the terms meaningless)  No, you should not store this in redux state, or local storage.  Cookies have much more security built-in.  (secure-only, http-only, same-site, etc... should be set)